# How do I fix "Execution failed for task 'compileJava'" error. (Using Intellij Idea and Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, discord-jda

Ok, I am coding a Discord Bot with JDA in Intellij Idea and I am using botCommons for Embeds. Using Gradle and Having imported the botCommons jar file. That was successful. However. I have attempted to start up the bot and had this issue in the console:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.afollestad:ason:1.4.16.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/ason-1.4.16.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/ason-1.4.16.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/ason-1.4.16.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/ason-1.4.16.jar
       - https://jitpack.io/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/ason-1.4.16.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/ason-1.4.16.jar
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > com.github.duncte123:botCommons:fbb8f98
```

I have my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id'java'
    id'application'
    id'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.4'
}

mainClassName = 'me.ntmnathan.RoryMercury.Main'

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.dv8tion', name: 'JDA', version: '3.8.0_434'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    compile group: 'com.github.duncte123', name: 'botCommons', version: 'fbb8f98'
    compile group: 'com.afollestad', name: 'ason', version: '1.4.16'

}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Sorry, I am kinda new to Java Discord Bot Development but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.afollestad:ason:1.4.16` is located at:
https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/com/afollestad/ason/1.4.16/

You need to add one more repository to your `repositories` list:

`maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }`

---

For next time, this answer was found by:

- Google [`com.afollestad:ason:1.4.16`](https://www.google.com/search?q=com.afollestad%3Aason%3A1.4.16)
- Click the [`com.afollestad » ason » 1.4.16 - Maven Repository`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.afollestad/ason/1.4.16) search result link
- Read the note:

  > Note: this artifact it located at Spring Lib Release repository (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/)

Comment: Awesome, it fixed. Thank you. I'll keep note of the artifact

Answer (score 0):

OK:

1. Your Gradle build failed because it could not find this dependency:

   ```
   compile group: 'com.afollestad', name: 'ason', version: '1.4.16'
   ```
2. A quick google search confirmed that it appears to be available on MavenRepository:

   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.afollestad/ason/1.4.6
3. But the same link shows that you need to add this to your build.gradle:

> Note: this artifact it located at Spring Plugins repository
>   (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/)

4. So change this:

   ```
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      mavenCentral()

      maven { 
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
      }
      maven { 
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/'
      }
   ```